# Slickgrid grid-menu is not moving along with grid when we load grid in ngb modal and scroll

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I am rendering an angular slickgrid on a ngb modal. When I open the grid-menu and scroll vertically the grid moves but grid-menu doesn't move along with grid menu-button. It stays at the same position.

What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: the Grid Menu is appended to the HTML body at the position it was opened, it does not follow the grid, it will always stay at the position it was opened (it's not part of the grid, it really is appended to the body which is why it does what you described). Perhaps what you could do is close the Grid Menu (via its addon instance) when the `onScroll` is triggered to avoid user confusion

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, there is no other way we can make it work than to close the menu on scroll?

Comment: not unless you want to contribute to the project to fix it... but anyway I'm not an expert in CSS and I don't see how that would be doable since the Grid Menu is not attached to the grid itself, it's just positioned were you clicked the button.